# Need a toggle menu that closes when it loses focus

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

This is going to be difficult to explain but bear with me.

I'm creating an application in WPF using the MVVM pattern. I'm new to it which is why I'm asking this question.

I have the application set up as 3 pages or views within a window. One of these is static and is always there, the other two are a couple of small settings pages that open in the top corner over the top of everything using zindex. At the moment the menu that opens these pages uses a listbox with togglebuttons as it's template (the checked state is bound to the listbox) so that you can click to open the menu, then click the button again to close it.

In an ideal world I'd like it so that if the menu page were to lose focus (listen for a click on the static view?) the settings views close too. Also I wondered if anyone had a simpler solution for a menu that works in a similar way because at the moment it is a pretty messy solution. Here are some code samples:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding PageViewModels}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Margin="10,0" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FCCC"/>
                    <ToggleButton
                            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Content=""
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
                            />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <!-- Settings views -->
    <ContentControl Panel.ZIndex="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/>

    <!-- Main page view -->
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="1000" Height="700" Content="{Binding StaticPageViewModel}"/>
```

I'm using the concepts in this **[blog post](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)** to manage my views and viewmodels, however I changed the way the menu is shown so I could remove the need for a change page command/ICommand.

TL;DR : I'm looking for suggestions and criticism with what I could do to improve the way I've currently created my menu bar.

Comment: Define close, you mean hide the toggle menu when it loses focus?

Comment: No I mean to close the views they represent, sorry I didn't make that clear. Basically at the moment the two way binding makes the `CurrentPageViewModel` Property null so the views are closed.

Comment: So you want a toggle button that closes "views"?

Comment: well it already does, but I wanted to see if I could make it so that if the view lost focus (i.e. clicks on the main view) then it closes.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an attached property if you really wanna do the MVVM style to close the View when it loses focus.

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseViewOnLostFocusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CloseViewOnLostFocus", typeof (object), typeof (MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(object), RegisterLostFocus));

    private static void RegisterLostFocus(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        //This is the control that is attached to it e.g. ContentControl
        var sender = dependencyObject as FrameworkElement;

        //Your ViewModel
        var viewModel = dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue as ViewModel;
        if (sender != null)
        {
            sender.LostFocus += (o, args) =>
                {
                    //Close whatever you are doing right now to close the View.
                    viewModel.Close();
                };
        }
    }
```

And on your view you can attach whatever ViewModel you want to close when it loses focus e.g. your SettingsView got LostFocus it'll close that view. In here I created an attached property on my MainWindow class.

```
    <!-- Settings views -->
    <ContentControl
MainWindow.CloseViewOnLostFocus="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content}"
x:Name="SettingsView" Panel.ZIndex="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/>

    <!-- Main page view -->
    <ContentControl x:Name="MainPageView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="1000" Height="700" Content="{Binding StaticPageViewModel}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `ContextMenu` attached to the button, which is opened when the button is clicked. This way, the close-when-unfocused behaviour is entirely automatic.

You can then just restyle the menu to look however you want.